# Average distance between sample and all group of samples in python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, distance

I have a set of samples, where each sample is specified by a vector (values), with their cluster number.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'samples': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'values': [[5, 0, 2, 2],[1, 6, 0, 2],[7, 2, 0, 0],[3, 6, 0, 0],[7, 0, 0, 2]], 'cluster': [1, 0, 2, 0, 1]})
df
```

output:

```
samples values  cluster
0   A   [5, 0, 2, 2]    1
1   B   [1, 6, 0, 2]    0
2   C   [7, 2, 0, 0]    2
3   D   [3, 6, 0, 0]    0
4   E   [7, 0, 0, 2]    1
```

I need to compute the average distance from each sample to all clusters;

For example, for sample A, its vector change from [5, 0, 2, 2], I would like to compute the average distance from sample A to its cluster (1), and to other clusters (0 and 2).

The expected output for A:

```
the average distance for A to cluster 0: 0.435
the average distance for A to cluster 1: 0.129
the average distance for A to cluster 2: 0.652
```

Comment: Please see: [Why is Can someone help me? not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)  for more details.

Comment: Are you asking about the average distance from A to the cluster or just the distance from A to the cluster centroid

Comment: @StonedTensor the average distance from A to all cluster (0, 1 and 2)

Comment: So for each instance (A), do you want one number that is the average from A to all centroids? That's a little different from the example you provide, which is the distance from A to the _average_ of the cluster (the centroid)

Comment: Also, how are you computing distance from A to the cluster?

Comment: @StonedTensor I want to calcuate the avg distance between A and all clusters, so there are three results that represent avg distance from A to clusters 0,1, and 2.  I used squareform(pdist(data)) to display all distances between first point and the other points. but for any sample and cluster, i dnot know how!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few steps:

1. You need to first find the average of each cluster, which is called a centroid. A centroid is the average of each dimension defining the cluster. As an example, let's consider cluster 1:

```
  samples   values   cluster
0   A   [5, 0, 2, 2]    1
4   E   [7, 0, 0, 2]    1
```

The centroid of cluster 1 is `[(5+7)/2, (0+0)/2, (2+0)/2, (2+2)/2] = [6,0,1,2]`. If you have `values` as a `numpy` array, you can run it as `np.mean(values, axis = 1)` to get this result.

2. Once you have your centroids, save them as a new variable (such as `centroids`).
3. From there, loop through your `values` and `centroid` arrays and call `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean(current_value,current_centroid)` (probably just `euclidean` for you). More specifically, something like:

```
for current_value in values:
    for current_centroid in centroids:
        print(euclidean(current_value, current_centroid))
```

4. You'll likely want to store each instance (like A) and its values as a dictionary, along with the centroids, for ease of use and interpretation. Your final dictionary could look like

```
distance_values_centroids = {"A":{0:euclidean(value_for_A,centroid_cluster_0), 
     1: euclidean(value_for_A,centroid_cluster_1)} 
    ... 
 }
```

5. At the end, you can create a `pandas` dataframe out of it with `pd.DataFrame(distance_values_centroids)`. From there, you have each instance and its distance to each centroid.

Comment: FYI: this is not exactly copy/paste but a method for you to find the distances and turn them back into a pandas dataframe, but you will need to do some of the work yourself

Comment: @ StonedTensor thank you for your help, could I use Wasserstein as a metric to calculate the distance in this scenario using AgglomerativeClustering?

Comment: If you'd like, of course. Just use `wasserstein` instead of `euclidean` as long as its included within `scipy`